# what are some limitations for using meteorites as evidence for the Earth's age?

Tags: homework, meteorite

I'm currently doing a question at the moment which is:

> Evaluate the usefulness and limitations of evidence provided by meteorites of Earth's age.

I'm having trouble finding some limitations at the moment if anyone could help that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Start by reading this: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2830/725 and you will hopefully get some ideas.